# Certain UI elements missing

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, interface

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04 and I've noticed that certain UI elements have gone missing. For some reason certain dialogues no longer have sliders, drop down menus, text boxes or buttons. It only happens with certain dialogues but for those dialogues it happens every time.

Here is an example of the permissions dialogue:

[image: The permissions dialogue]

The password text box is gone and any check boxes or buttons are also missing.

Comment: It almost sounds like a Style that has been picked in the Appearance in the Settings may not be working correctly.  Try a different Style and see if that fixes it.

Comment: As Terrance suggests, change themes. Try a standard theme like the default Greybird to assure yourself that nothing is really broken. Some theme designers seem to favor reduced contrast!

Comment: If you like dark themes, try Adwaita-Dark which is probably already installed on your system.

Comment: I did try changing themes but all it did was change the colors. The buttons were still missing? Do I need to logout/restart after selecting a new theme?